# is it possible to run Scan Beacon when app is Killed

Tags: dart, background, beacon, scanning

**Hello I'm new developer so i need some help Now. I was Bullied app doing Brodcast and Scan Beacon i used [flutter_beacon 0.3.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon)

and for Brodcast i use [beacon_broadcast 0.2.1](http://beacon_broadcast%200.2.1) its working good for Advertising and Scan event when app is Background,but when app is kill or i remove app from list Running applications the Scan and Brodcast not Working 
 Now My Question is How to running code scan and Brodcast  when app is killed or Finished ???**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, it is absolutely possible to resume beacon scanning on both Android and iOS** after an app is killed.  But the specifics of how you do this are different between iOS and Android.  Further, **the use of non-native development frameworks like FlutterBeacon make things more complicated as the documentation is not as complete for this use case.**

While I am not an expert on FlutterBeacon, I am the lead developer on the underlying Android Beacon Library which it uses under the hood.  I am also very familiar with how iOS CoreLocation works (which it also uses under the hood.)

In general here are the rules to get apps to detect after being killed:

**iOS:**

- Start beacon monitoring (not just ranging) in the didFinishLaunching method of the AppDelegate
- Obtain ALWAYS Location permission
- After the app is killed it will be re-launched in the background when all beacons disappear or the  first beacon appears in a monitored region.

**Android:**

- Start beacon monitoring in the onCreate method of an Android application class using RegionBootstrap.  [See here for a discussion on the FlutterBeacon github](https://github.com/alann-maulana/flutter_beacon/issues/45#issuecomment-609585808)
- Obtain BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission from the user.
- On Android 8+, your app should restart within 25 minutes of being killed and give you a callback to the BootstrapNotifier methods as appropriate.